# getting api response in every 30 mins in ionic app automatically

Tags: ionic-framework

I am making an Ionic app and I want to receive a response from api in every 30 mins on its own to send notification to the user, even if the app isn't currently running or even if the app has not been started.

Comment: is this ionic 3 or 4 ?

Comment: i want to do it in ionic  4.